# Stack Exchange: Should some communities simply be "sub-communities" of other sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51

While browsing through Area 51 I came across a proposal for an [Ubuntu](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7716/ubuntu) Stack Exchange site, and a similar [Linux/UNIX site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3924/unix-linux).

To me, this is obviously a subset of superuser.com. There is a small debate about this on area51. Quoting:

> I think this is better than SuperUser because it's focused on Ubuntu, allowing those not interested in Ubuntu to ignore this content entirely rather than spamming it. I think it's better than the proposal you link to for the same reason. Ubuntu forums is a mess, and StackEngine is an extremely effective and well-designed platform for creating a knowledge base. The forums have served us well but forum threads quickly become unwieldy and they do not age well. – David Siegel Jun 20 at 17:40

It seems to me that a technical solution could solve this.

You could have a Stack Exchange site that operates against the same database as superuser.com, but forces every question to be tagged "ubuntu" and only ever displays questions tagged "ubuntu". This would make everybody happy, since if you only care about Ubuntu and no other operating systems that are discussed on superuser.com, you can easily filter everything else without any configuration hassles. If you care about the community on superuser.com, you get a larger number of people who are providing quality questions and answers - easily filtered by their subject of choice.

The same could be said about Stack Overflow; you could create "sub-sites" for different programming languages, etc.

Comment: If filtering is the problem, fix that. Splitting up a site into smaller tags would be a horrible idea

Comment: Care to explain why you think it's a horrible idea? You could make the argument that superuser.com by itself is too broad; that you would need a specifically "branded" site for some topics (tags) discussed there to get the community more involved. Every minute someone has to spend configuring filters may lead to the loss of a potential community member. And as the recent stackoverflow blog post pointed out, (paraphrasing) people don't trust things that are in a series. So even if you fixed filtering and had ubuntu.superuser.com, people still might not "trust" it (presumably).

Comment: there are just too many sites out there... if there are 32 different programming sites, why would anyone frequent all of them, or even all of the ones covering the same area? I barely have time enough to frequent stackoverflow + superuser.